# how to append a hyperlink from a json file to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, url, hyperlink

I am using jQuery to parse and display data from a JSON file. I got everything to spit out in the browser but one of the keys in my JSON file has a url as the value. I'm trying to make it show up as a link and it keeps giving me an error.

Here's my json:

```
{
  "website" : {
    "url" : "http://www.stuffinmagazines.com"
  },
  "phone1" : "222-444-4853",
  "business" : "Stuff Inc."
}
```

and my jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if (val.item.search(myExp) != -1) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<p>' + "Website: " + '<a href = ' + val.website.url + '>' + URL + '</a>' + '</p>';
                output += '<p>' + "Phone: " + val.phone + '</p>';
                output += '<p>' + "Business: " + val.business + '</p>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('#update').html(output);
```

i guess i'm not putting the val.website.url correctly...anyone know how to retrieve url's from json files?

Comment: `<a href = "' + val.website.url + '">URL</a>'`

Comment: didnt work please explain your answer :)

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: script.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Comment: This means that "website" is undefined in one of the files, not "url".

Comment: You each expects an array - pls post a more complete JSON example

Answer (score 0):

This part looks wrong:

```
'<a href = ' + val.website.url + '</a>'
```

Assuming `val.website.url` has the url, that bit should be:

```
'<a href = "' + val.website.url + '"></a>'
```

We could build the `<a>` element like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">A place to put the link<div>

<script>
  // not using http: in url makes it work for both http: & https: 
  var url = "//jsfiddle.net";

  var el = $("<a />"); // a virtual <a> element

  // put url and some text to click on into our virtual element
  el.prop('href',url).text('click here'); 

  $("#myDiv").html(el); // put the element into the page
</script>
```

[click here for the jsfiddle](http:////jsfiddle.net/dieter_donnert/a58L80vz/)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing double quotes try below 
`'<a href = "' + val.website.url + '">URL</a>'`